# How to access constant variable inside return statement?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Following is my code:

```
const keyToDisplayMessage = 'REGULAR_HOME';

const cf = format(
    {
      accountName: this.accountName,
    },
    this.pageData.sucessMessages.keyToDisplayMessage,
    this.$route.name
);
    
return cf;
```

In this `keyToDisplayMessage` does not get replaced by `REGULAR_HOME`. However, if I directly use it like

```
this.pageData.sucessMessages.REGULAR_HOME
```

then it works.

How can I access `keyToDisplayMessage` inside the format function?

Comment: Use bracket notation instead of dot notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically accessing the property use bracket notation .Update this .

```
this.pageData.sucessMessages.keyToDisplayMessage
```

to

```
this.pageData.sucessMessages[keyToDisplayMessage]
```

Comment: Glad it helped you ! Happy Learning !